# How to make localStorage and Cookies work like normal browsers in React Native?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native

Is there a way to configure localStorage and Cookies work like normal browsers in React Native?
Some websites or Web SDKs are using them to store login information.
The problem is that when I restart the React Native app, the user session is not recovered and I think it is because of the `localStorage` and `Cookies`
Any good solutions?

Comment: Any particular reason to not use [asyncstorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)?

Comment: As per React Native documentation this should be used instead of LocalStorage > "It should be used instead of LocalStorage."

Comment: I can save and load specific values manually but my goal is to make the Javascript SDKs working as normal.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, storing "login information" in "local" might not be a good idea.

I don't have any information about how you are handling the authentication, or if you are only trying to use the local storage for in a "Remember me" way, for everytime user opens the app you will need to authenticate the user again. Using a 3rd party for this is your best and simplest bet. See auth0.com or similar services.

Also `AsyncStorage` is the equivalent of for localStorage in react-native.

See the documentation;

> https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html

Comment: My goal is not the manual usage of any kind of storages by my codes.

Comment: I want to build an environment the same as the browser in React Native to enable cookies and localStorage. By doing that, for example Web SDKs will be working as normal, as in the browser. A good example is using Firebase Web SDK (Auth) in React Native.